# test of a value during an update

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of creating a request which allows to validate several fields. So far it works.

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"] == "validate") {
    try {
        
        $id = implode(",", $_POST['id']);
        $s  = $connect->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET etat = '1' WHERE id in(" . $id . ")");
        $s->execute();
?><div class="alert alert-success">
 OK
</div><?php
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
 NOK
</div><?php
    }
}
?>
```

I want to test a field named city, which is a field from table1, on the validated fields.
In fact when I update my table1 table, I would like to test the value of the city field, if this field == 'Paris' I increment a counter named cpt.
Is there a way to do this because I'm crashing on it.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: this is insecure and vulnerable to **sql injection** use only **prapred statements with parameters**

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by, 'I would like to test the value of the city field, if this field == 'Paris' I increment a counter named cpt'. Is the field/value coming from the submitted form or is it the value in `table1`?

Comment: Perhaps you could show the code you're having trouble with, rather than the code that works?

Comment: Can you tell please how to do it

Comment: before updating you need to get first the table1 city column value  for the $id and then check the city == paris then increment the $cpt

Comment: `Can you tell please how to do it` - assuming you mean `prepared statements`, https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in

Comment: Yes it is a value in table1

Comment: How can i  get the table1 city column value for the $id and then check the city == paris then increment the $cpt ?

Comment: I'd issue 2 UPDATE statements, your 2nd one would be `UPDATE table1 SET cpt= '1' WHERE city = 'Paris' AND id IN (?);`

Comment: but cpt is a variable but not a value in a table

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please edit it with more details.

Comment: I have a table named table1 with the fields id, last_name, first_name, city.
With the program I put above I can validate several fields by clicking on the validate button.
I want, for the selected elements, to count the number of fields with the city field = 'paris'.
I hope it's clear

Comment: Not really. Please _edit_ your question (don't just type comments here) with the validation logic, HTML form, etc. so we can actually see what you mean.

Comment: By the looks of it, you want to count how many rows with `city = 'paris'` were validated, so you could just run a 2nd query similar to the one proposed by @waterloomatt, but as a `SELECT`, right after your `UPDATE` : `SELECT count(*) AS cpt FROM table1 WHERE city = 'Paris' AND id IN (?);`

Comment: Thank you, i have added

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i have added
`$s1=$connect->prepare('SELECT count(*) AS cpt FROM table1 WHERE city = 'Paris' AND id IN (".$id.")"); $result = $s1->execute;` 
And i have the good result when i wrote
`
OK `<?php echo $result ; ?>`

But so far in the script when i want test the value of $result it's always equals to 0

Comment: You really need to read a tutorial on prepared statements and how to retrieve data. Start here - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn. There is a lot of information in this one so go through it carefully.

Comment: Also, read the documentation and especially around inputs and return values - you'll see that `execute` returns a boolean. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues